# SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, database-connection

We have an Excel file from which it retrieves information from a SQL Server DB.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
   Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mjone;Initial  Catalog=pff_db;Data Source=....
```

My question is that for mjone, how is he able to get connected to the SQL Server DB? I am looking at the SQL Server Management Studio and do not see any mjone used.

Comment: Check these:

1. Check the users under `pff_db`
2. Check global SQL Server Users
3. Check if that user exists in the server (Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these:

```
 Check the users under `pff_db`
 Check global SQL Server Users
 Check if that user exists in the server (Windows)
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It is under pff_db,  I do see a user called mjone. How does the password work. Meaning it is not specified in the connection string. How does that user then have the ability to connect to the db without a password?

Comment: You can check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/216fae16-18e4-4c62-b75e-9550b8d524d8/) thread. It has some info